# Sum of quantities using siunitx

Tags: siunitx, units

I'm trying to display the sum of two numbers using the `siunitx` package. Specifically, I'm trying to write out the conversion from Celsius to Kelvin. Ideally, I'd like to display the following equation:

5°C = (5+273) K = 278 K

I see that `siunitx` has a `product-units` option that can be used to display products of quantities. For example:

---

**Code**

```
\SI[product-units = brackets]{2 x 3 x 4}{\metre}
```

**Output**

(2 × 3 × 4) m

---

I've also seen that `multi-part-units` can be used to display numbers with multiple parts (such as uncertainty). For example:

---

**Code**

```
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\SI[multi-part-units = brackets]{12.3(4)}{\kilo\gram}
```

**Output**

(12.3 ± 0.4) kg

---

So, I'm able to display both the product of two numbers as well as one quantity plus or minus another quantity, but I cannot seem to figure out how to simply display one number plus another number using the `siunitx` package. Am I missing something obvious, or is this simply not possible? I could generate the desired content without `siunitx`, but since I am using that package throughout the rest of my document, it would be nice to use it in this case as well for the sake of consistency.

Comment: `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(5+273)}{\kelvin}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @egreg mentioned you can tell [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to not to bother with the number parsing with `parse-numbers=false` option. Or if the output is too complicated to be parsed then you can simply skip the numerical part and put the unit with the lowercase version `\si{}` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(5+273)}{\kelvin}

$(5+273)\,\si{\kelvin}$
\end{document}
```

Note the spacing in the second version.